# Using gdal_rasterize with a MSSQL Connection, possible?

Tags: sql-server-spatial, gdal-rasterize

I'm a bit new to gdal, I mostly use ogr2ogr for data imports to MS SQL Server -- so I'm a bit out of my tree on gdal_rasterize

My goal is to create png raster files 200x200 from a geometry column.  I tried something like with no avail.

```
gdal_rasterize -src_datasource "MSSQL:server={server};database=
     {database};uid={user};pwd={pwd};" -a geom -l layer1 -of png -burn 
     255 -b geom -sql "SELECT top 1 geom from {myTable}" tract.png -of png -ts 200 200
```

Comment: Does `ogrinfo "MSSQL:server={server};database=
     {database};uid={user};pwd={pwd};" -sql "SELECT top 1 geom from {myTable}"` read data?

Comment: The only thing that happens is that I get the Usage output:

    Usage: gdal_rasterize [-b band]* [-i] [-at]
       [-burn value]* | [-a attribute_name] [-3d]
       [-l layername]* [-where expression] [-sql select_statement]
        ...


According the documentation, data_source can be from a database

Comment: You must find the correct syntax for making ogrinfo and gdal_rasterize to work. If you import successfully data already with ogr2ogr you must have a good example available. I suppose that you use the same GDAL and it is listing the driver with ogrinfo --formats. Read also examples from http://www.gdal.org/drv_mssqlspatial.html.